# Filter out rows with NaN values for certain column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset and in some of the rows an attribute value is `NaN`. This data is loaded into a dataframe and I would like to only use the rows which consist of rows where all attribute have values. I tried doing it via sql:

```
val df_data = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM raw_data WHERE attribute1 != NaN")
```

I tried several variants on this, but I can't seem to get it working.

Another option would be to transform it to a RDD and then filter it, since filtering this dataframe to check if a attribute `isNaN` , does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some sample code that shows you my way of doing it -

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq((1, 0.5), (2, Double.NaN))).toDF("id", "value")
val df2 = df.explode[Double, Boolean]("value", "isNaN")(d => Seq(d.isNaN))
```

df will have -

```
df.show

id value
1  0.5  
2  NaN
```

while doing filter on df2 will give you what you want -

```
df2.filter($"isNaN" !== true).show

id value isNaN
1  0.5   false
```

Answer (score 12):

I know you accepted the other answer, but you can do it without the `explode` (which should perform better than doubling your DataFrame size).

**Prior to Spark 1.6**, you could use a `udf` like this:

```
def isNaNudf = udf[Boolean,Double](d => d.isNaN)
df.filter(isNaNudf($"value"))
```

**As of Spark 1.6**, you can now use the built-in [**SQL function**](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) `isnan()` like this:

```
df.filter(isnan($"value"))
```

Comment: `df.filter(isnan($"value"))` returns all the rows with "value" as NaN right?

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
where isNaN(tau_doc) = false
```

e.g.

```
val df_data = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM raw_data where isNaN(attribute1) = false")
```